# Is the first predicate in effect when I reference the first table after using a predicate to filter it, then in a second predicate on another table?

Tags: oracle, row-level-security

Using the Oracle VPD facility(aka RLS, aka FGAC), suppose that I use the predicate

```
(WHERE) id = 'XXXX'
```

on `TableA` and then I use the predicate

```
(WHERE) col in (SELECT col From TableA)
```

on `TableB`.

Will `TableA` be filtered or not? Is filtering is done only outside of predicate definitions, when you query the tables?
Will I need to make predicate on `TableB` like this?:

```
(WHERE) col in (SELECT col From TableA where id ='XXXX')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `TableA` will be automatically filtered using the predicate you specified `(id = 'XXXX')`.
Oracle automatically applies the filters wherever you use (`select from`, in this case) the table, even in sub-queries, if the filter criteria is met (see sec_relevant_cols).